# Python : Getting a handle to imported modules

Tags: python, python-2.6, python-module

I have written an application that gives the user an option to specify a particular network scanning tool (say nmap,xprobe,p0f) and then scans a given subnet with that tool (I do not re-implement the tool, simply call it in shell and parse its response for my app), parses the result and stores in a particular format in DB. This application is basically a feeder application for another app that will use the data in DB.

I have written my code so that all Scan Tool interfaces are implemented as plug-ins. The  structure is

```
Project/
   DBWriter.py 
   Scanner/
      __init__.py
      network_mapper.py
      Scanner.py
      Plugins/
         __init__.py
         nmap.py
         p0f.py
   Others/
```

So to add a new scan interface, all the developer needs to do is write a tool.py file (in correct semantics ofcourse) and drop it into Plugins folder.

To achieve this I need to be able to import correct python module at run-time.

```
from Plugins import nmap
or
from Plugins import xprobe
```

Depending on what the user enters

Here's the code that I have added

```
f,p,d = imp.find_module("Plugins")
x = imp.load_module("Plugins",f,p,d)
path_n = x.__path__
f,p,d = imp.find_module("%s"%(tool),path_n)
tool_mod = imp.load_module("%s"%(tool),f,p,d)
tool_mod.scan() #Irrespective of what user enters or what new plugin is  developed, this line does not need to change and will work as long as plug-in has a scan function
```

The code works correctly. However, when I try to bundle it into one executable using [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) (for Windows/*Nix platforms), it has a lot of trouble in find_module and load_module and consequently I get an ImportError (maybe its because the paths are not correctly unrolled in executable decompression).

My question is - Is there an alternate way in Python using which I can achieve the same functionality (that might hopefully work well with PyInstaller) ?

I had earlier asked this question looking for workarounds in PyInstaller, but no responses have forced me to look for workarounds in Python

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to run on Windows, then I recommend trying [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/).

> py2exe is a Python Distutils extension which converts Python scripts into executable Windows programs, able to run without requiring a Python installation.

We use it at work to speed up a very large Python program, and it copes with imported modules.

Comment: That would be a way out, but I was looking for a cross-platform option which PyInstaller provides (almost beautifully)

Comment: OK. It might be worth adding a note to your question to say which platforms you need.